# Understanding CompositeDisposable in RxJava + Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java, android-lifecycle, rx-binding

I am using RxJava for form validation for validating username and password.
My use-case is pretty simple if both the fields satisfy respective condition then enable the login button else to disable it.
following is my code.

```
    lateinit var subscriptions: CompositeDisposable
    private fun validateForm() {
        val emailObservable = viewBinding.detUserName.editText.textChangeEvents()
            .skipInitialValue()
            .map { isValidEmail(it.text) || isValidPhoneNumber(it.text) }
            .doOnDispose {
                Log.i("disposed", "emailObservable")
            }


        val passwordObservable = viewBinding.detPassword.editText.textChangeEvents()
            .skipInitialValue()
            .map { !TextUtils.isEmpty(it.text) }
            .doOnDispose {
                Log.i("disposed", "passwordObservable")
            }

        val disposable = Observable.combineLatest(emailObservable, passwordObservable,
            BiFunction<Boolean, Boolean, Boolean> { t1, t2 -> t1 && t2 }).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe {
                viewBinding.bLogin.isEnabled = it
            }
        subscriptions.add(disposable)
    }

fun isValidEmail(target: CharSequence): Boolean {
        return !TextUtils.isEmpty(target) && android.util.Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(target).matches()
    }

    fun isValidPhoneNumber(target: CharSequence): Boolean {
        return !TextUtils.isEmpty(target) && Pattern.compile("(05|9665)[0-9]{8}").matcher(target).matches()
    }
```

I am **subscription** is a CompositeDisposable object reference which i am creating in onCreate and onResume(if not created or already cleared/disposed)
and disposing it in onStop()

**Edit**

**following is part of my base fragment**

```
 override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        createDisposable()
    }

    protected fun createDisposable() {
        if (!this::subscriptions.isInitialized) {
            subscriptions = CompositeDisposable()
        }
    }
   override fun onStop() {
        super.onStop()
        disposeAll()
    }

    protected fun disposeAll() {
        if (this::subscriptions.isInitialized) {
            subscriptions.clear()
        }
    }
```

**my login fragment**

```
override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        validateForm()
    }
```

For the first time **Observable.combineLatest** is working fine, but the problem is once the app goes into the background and resumes it's not firing again.
when it went into background onStop() calls clear the compositeDisposable disposing of all the disposables, when it resumes I am re-adding new instance of disposables to compositeDisposable still, it's not firing.
I am not able to figure out a way to fix this, any leads will be appreciated.

Comment: do you call `validateForm()` again when activity start?

Comment: yes I do in onResume() @PhanVanLinh please check my edits

Comment: You can use rxbinding, which is very easy to implement. See [snippet](https://guides.codepath.com/android/RxJava-and-RxBinding).

Comment: @AbuNoman i am using the same thing, please check my code again. its kotlin extension provided by rxbinding, but i don't think that is an issue

Answer (score 0):

Initialize `CompositeDisposable` in your login fragment and add all `disposable` to the `CompositeDisposable` and clear it `onPause`. Looks like:

```
private var subscriptions: CompositeDisposable = CompositeDisposable()

private fun validateForm() {
    val emailObservable = viewBinding.detUserName.editText.textChangeEvents()
        .skipInitialValue()
        .map { isValidEmail(it.text) || isValidPhoneNumber(it.text) }
        .doOnDispose {
            Log.i("disposed", "emailObservable")
        }


    val passwordObservable = viewBinding.detPassword.editText.textChangeEvents()
        .skipInitialValue()
        .map { !TextUtils.isEmpty(it.text) }
        .doOnDispose {
            Log.i("disposed", "passwordObservable")
        }

    val disposable = Observable.combineLatest(emailObservable, passwordObservable,
        BiFunction<Boolean, Boolean, Boolean> { t1, t2 -> t1 && t2 }).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribe {
            viewBinding.bLogin.isEnabled = it
        }
    subscriptions.add(emailObservable, passwordObservable, disposable)
}

override fun onResume() {
    super.onResume()
    validateForm()
}

override fun onPause() {
    subscriptions.clear()
    super.onPause()
}
```

Comment: did you test it ?